# Get File from path on Angular or how to Programatically Post MultiPart File Request

Tags: angular, post, multipartform-data

As I'm dynamically uploading images, I want for now, to just send one to my POST url.
From PAW/Postman my endpoint works when I send the file as multipart :

```
--__X_PAW_BOUNDARY__
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="blouse1.png" 
Content-Type: image/png
```

On Angular I try this:

```
const file = fs.readFileSync(imgPath, 'utf8');
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", file);

// interceptor adds content type:  multipart/form-data
return this.http.post<any>(url, formData)
  .pipe(map((result) => result));
```

}

And the backend receives no file.

The Angular request on CURL includes :

```
 --data-binary $'------WebKitFormBoundarysAgZBIaWrsIKE5Z4\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"\r\n\r\n[object Object]\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarysAgZBIaWrsIKE5Z4--\r\n' --compressed --insecure
```

While the PAW Curl just :

```
     -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=__X_PAW_BOUNDARY__' \
 -F "file="
```

I'm trying to find the way to get a File instead the contents by reading fs.readFileSync.  This should be something as simple as fs.getFile(path), to mimic what happen when using a file upload form. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This read and file creation works, but sounds like a workaround.

```
const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(imgPath);
const file = new File([fileContents], img);
const formData: any = new FormData();
formData.append("file", file);
```